No route to host (SSH) depending on the client
I am running sshd on port 22222 on a Fedora machine and tested ssh connection from a Mac within LAN and everything works. I also set up port forwarding from the router to my fedora machine and allowed incoming ipv6 connections.
Now the issue is that, depending on the client and network from which I try to ssh, it either works or gives 'No route to host' error.
Given the above I think the server side is configured correctly, also using https://portchecker.co/check-it it appears that the port 22222 is open.
From my Mac I can ping successfully, although I get 'No route to host' when trying to ssh, meanwhile trying to ssh (ipv4 though) to some other servers from the same mac and network worked.
Ssh from another client worked successfully. Any clues on what could be the issue?

Could be anything. At least provide some technical  information, otherwise we can offer no help. Routing tables, network-diagram etc.

You first say that SSH-ing from your Mac to the Fedora machine works; then you say that you get "No route to host" when trying to SSH from the Mac to the Fedora machine. It's unclear whether the SSH clients that fail to connect to your IPv6-enabled host are themselves IPv6-enabled or not.

No from my Mac it only works on LAN, over the internet I can only ping it but cannot ssh. From another fedora machine (but also another network) I was able to ssh over the internet. Don't know if it's helpful but I can share the ipv6

Well well, you mention IPv6. So I am wondering how you connect to the SSH server. Do you use a hostname or a plain IP address? Is it IPv4 or IPv6, or both? IPv4 and IPv6 are distinct network stacks, they each have their own routing, firewall rules etc.

I tried connect via plain Ipv6 address. I figured out what is the issue, simply two networks I tried do not have ipv6 connectivity meanwhile my friend's one does. I tested ipv6 connectivity with https://test-ipv6.com/
